# How to customize the fields order and widget using the default templates in grails 3?

Tags: templates, grails, field, grails-orm, grails3

I would like to set the order of the fields displayed in the default templates of grails 3 (using the f:all, f:table tags etc). I would also like to specify the widget to use for the field without specifying a different template for it (I know about http://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html and have created some custom templates for other fields). For example to just use TextArea rather than Text field. Can it somehow be controlled by the settings or contraints from the Model?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the constraints determines the order of the scaffolding. To specify a `textarea` intead of `input` you can specify a widget:

```
description widget: 'textarea'
```

Some [documentation here](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Constraints/widget.html).